# For loop to populate object info from a list of tuples

Tags: python

I would like to add info to objects, extracting that info from a list.

The expected result would be to have an object that when printed (method "results" in class) shows something like this:

```
Account name = user1@example.com
Number of failed logins = 3
Number of Origin IPs = 2
OIPs used = ["192.168.1.1", "192.168.1.2"]
Client or protocols = ["SMTP"]
```

I do have a list of objects which only have the "account_name" plus the constructor defaults. I also have a list with all the required info.

Extract of the List with all the required info:

```
list_count_occurrences=[(('user1@example.com', '192.168.1.1', 'SMTP'), 1), (('user2@example.com', '192.168.1.1', 'SMTP'), 6)]
```

The numbers at the end of the list, belong to the number of tries the that particular user, made from the same IP and using the same protocol. So it is possible to have same user, but from different IPs and/or protocols. All the values in the tuples are unique, meaning that if the same user uses another IP to login, then that attempt is reflected in the list as another "tuple", with the same user, different IP, same protocol, and a different count.

Class definition:

```
class Login():
def __init__(self,account):
    self.account_name = account
    self.failed_attempts = 0
    self.number_of_oips = 0
    self.oips = []
    self.origins = []

def results(self):
    print("Account name =", self.account_name)
    print("Number of failed logins =", self.failed_attempts)
    print("Number of Origin IPs =", self.number_of_oips)
    print("OIPs used =", self.oips)
    print("Client or protocols =", self.origins)
```

This is the latest form of my failed loops:

```
for item in list_count_occurrences:
    for object in list_of_objects:
        if object.account_name == list_count_occurrences[0][0][0]:
           object.origins.append(list_count_occurrences[0][0][2])
```

So what it should be nice log parser, becomes this when printed:

```
Account name = someuser@example.com
Number of failed logins = 0
Number of Origin IPs = 0
OIPs used = []
Client or protocols = ['SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP', 'SMTP']
```

Is like this loop is using the fixed positions used in the "if" statement, instead of using the values relative to each object being analized.

Any ideas? Thank you!!!

Comment: I'm a little confused. You loop over `list_count_occurrences` but you don't actually use the loop variable `item` in that loop, and instead you compare against `list_count_occurrences[0]` on each loop. Are you just trying to group all records related to the same user?

Comment: Use `for (email, ip, protocol), failed_count in list_count_occurrences:` for readability, and your own clarity inside the loop.

Comment: Omg, I can't belive this...I've been struggling for hours with this. Changing list_count_occurrences[0][0][0] for "item[0][0]" solved it. I was blinded and couldn't see that. Iguananaut, thank you so much for your help! Muhammad, thanks for the suggestion, I didn't know about that format for the loops, i'll try those too as you suggest:)